# How to get a android ListView item selector to use state_pressed

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I want to color to background of an image View when it get pressed.
I tried to do it with selector that changes the image for the different states (pressed and not pressed).
The problem now is that the image replaces the previous with the exact same size and I want it be to much larger.
I use a custom layout that implements checkable, and I tried also to overload the onCreateDrawableState function, but it never being called.

Help please..

This is how it looks:

before pressing:

[image]

after pressing:

[image]

This is the item list custom layout:

```
public class ListItem extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable, OnClickListener {

    private View mItemChecked = null;
    private ImageView imageSkinEdit = null;

    /*private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {
        android.R.attr.state_pressed
    };*/



    public ListItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ListItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ListItem(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        try {
            mItemChecked = this.findViewById(R.id.itemlist_checkedd);
            imageSkinEdit = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.skinEdit);
            imageSkinEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }//onFinishInflate

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        if(mItemChecked != null) {
            return ((Checkable)mItemChecked).isChecked();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if(mItemChecked != null) {
            if (checked) {
                mItemChecked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mItemChecked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        if(mItemChecked != null) {
            ((Checkable)mItemChecked).toggle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.skinEdit:
                //handleEdit();
                break;
        }//switch
    }

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        Log.d("onCreateDrawableState", "onCreateDrawableState");
        return super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        /*final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            Log.d("ListItem", "isChecked");
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }
        return drawableState;*/
    }
}
```

The selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_go_edit_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_go_edit" />
</selector>
```

Image View XML:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/skinEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/edit_skin_selector" />
```

Comment: edit your image "ic_go_edit_pressed" correctly

Comment: I have same problem too.

Comment: If you want to set the Selector to the ListView then dont put selector to the ImageView. Instead of it put it to the ParentLayout of the row.xml file of your ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did it using a different method. You can see it in my next [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162862/setting-imageview-background-issue-with-selector)

Answer (score 1):

Try calling refreshDrawableState() at the end of setChecked. That will get onCreateDrawableState to be called

```
  @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if(mItemChecked != null) {
            if (checked) {
                mItemChecked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mItemChecked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
            refreshDrawableState();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add a default state to your selector too

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand how it's going to help me. The pictures is already switched but with the same size, and I want with different size

Answer (score 0):

I have known, that onCreateDrawableState not call i.e. ListItem has not background drawable.