# Setting imageView background issue with selector 

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, selector

I have a problem with setting the click event in a list view item.

This is how the list is shown in the default situation:

[image]

This is how it looks when I press the red image (the red turns to blue):
[image]

and this is when I press the list item:
[image]

As you can see, the red image turns to blue also, Even though I didn't pressed the button. What I want is that when I press the list item there is no change to the red image, and it remains the same.

I tried to add `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` to xml file in listview section, but it didn't work. I also tried to fix it with the selector parameters, still with no success.

I uploaded some code, the next sections are in different xml files, so don't get confused.

**EDIT:** I want to use the OS item list background color and not my own color with `android:listSelector`, because that one I've already do.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/red"/> 

</selector>
```

-----------------------new file--------------------------------

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list_theme"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/contbtn_themelist"
    android:stackFromBottom="false"
    android:transcriptMode="disabled"/>
```

-----------------------new file--------------------------------

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/edit_back"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="77dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_skin_selector2"  >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/skinEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:** row.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="2dip"
        android:paddingRight="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemlist_checkedd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_checkitem" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/skinpreview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/itemlist_checkedd"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/edit_back"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_skin_selector2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/skinEdit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edit_back"
            android:src="@drawable/separator" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/separator"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/skinpreview"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Any help will be great, Thanks.

Comment: so you want is, If user click on the List item then action occurs but then red image is not turn in to the red and if user click on the red image then it turns in to the red and action occurs. am i right ? Please reply to this so i can help you.

Comment: @iDroid Explorer Basically you right, the only difference is that if the red turns to something, it will be different than red. Another thing, I want to use the OS list item colors, meaning, Orange in some systems and Blue at others. Thanks.

Comment: @Ok then wait for my answer. And let me know how much you got success in doing that ?

Comment: Please also put the row.xml file which you are use to inflate the row items.

Comment: if you want to use the Default OS list item color to the Image instead  of the red then use"@android:drawable/list_selector_background" as the background of that image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered this issue too, I solved it using the tecnique here:

http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=525

Look at the paragraph "Don't press everything!"

Comment: To avoid of writing new custom layout for any other views (`RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout`…), have a look at [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13813751/1521536), it's simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `android:duplicateParentState="false"` to indicate not to use the parent's drawable state for its child.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/skinEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" 

    android:duplicateParentState="false"
   />
```

### Update

Make your button's immediate parent non-clickable, i.e. add `android:clickable="false"` to it in row.xml and see if that fixes the problem. Now the click on item will not change the button state. But the click on button should still work I guess.

### update

```
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/skinEdit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:background="@android:drawable/state_redblue_drawable"
            android:padding=10dp
            android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not good, that didn't change anything.

Comment: I'm appreciate your efforts to help me, but it still not good, still the same problem. This is driving me nuts...

Comment: Still the same. When I press the item, the background of the button is shown to.

Comment: If you want the background of button to be larger than button image then use ImageButton. Set the image to src. and set state drawable to background.. can have some padding as well.

Comment: I tried it also, but for some reason when I change it I can't press the list item, meaning it can't be press able. Any suggestions?

Comment: I need to put it where? Again it's the item of the list that can't be clickable not the button, so at the root layout or what?

Comment: I put clickable=true in two places, one the root RL, and the other in edit_back RL, and this is causing a problem in pressing the list items, or in other words I can't press the list items, because they are still not click able.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution before.. I dont have the link, but you has to do this. Create a custom class for the linearlayout that contains your botton, then override the setPressed state to dont do anything;

```
public class UnpresseableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout
{
    public UnpresseableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

@Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed)
    {
        // Do nothing here. Specifically, do not propagate this message along
        // to our children so they do not incorrectly display a pressed state
        // just because one of their ancestors got pressed.
    }
}
```

this will solve the problem because the android:duplicateParentState="false" will not work in this case.

Replace then your linearlayout in your xml with this one, that cannot receive press actions

Edit:
Sorry, i just saw that you are using RelativeLayout.. but i supose that is the same.

Answer (score 0):

try making imageView clickable...

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/skinEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:focussable="false"
           android:focussableInTouchMode="false"
           android:clickable="true" />
```

or..

change selector state to

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/red"/> 

</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't worked. In the selector method when I click the button, it stays the same, meaning colored in red. In the first method I get the same attitude as I get before the change.

Comment: Like you said "OR" ,so I changed once the selector and afterwards the xml - only one of the method at a time.

Comment: minor note, there is a typo in the word `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode`  (you have an extra 's' in both)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. First of all Sorry for the Late reply.

Before going on solution let see what i get from your question.

You want is, when you click on List-items then that red image not convert in to Blue and if user click on the Red Image then it should be convert in to the Red. But not with whole list-Items right ???

If is it so, then there is nothing to do more.

Don't put selector. Selector is basically for, whenever you want to change the color of the background while you click on that particular view.

And yes if you want to change the color of the RedImage while user click on it then again don't use selector there. But Just change the Color of that Image during run time.

As like:

```
@Override 
        public void onClick(View view) { 
                 YOUR_VIEW.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);

        }
```

Hope it will help you. If its not work as what you want then let me know.

i will like to help you.

Enjoy.:)

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not good, now the background isn't colored when I press the button.

Comment: You mean if you click on the red button then that whole list-Item get Change color ??

Comment: @OfirAN: I am getting what you got right now with your question. But not getting what you want  ?? Please clarify what you actually want, so we can help you properly.

Comment: Let me clarify what I want. In the first Image(Red Background), this is when no touching is made, or in other words this is the default state. Then the user touches the button(with the red background) the background turns to blue(second picture), till now it's all working just fine. The next thing is the problematic state. When the user touches the list item both the background of the item is colored and the background of the button(third picture), and what I want is that only the background of the item will change his color and the button will stay in defualt state, meaninng red.

Comment: I have clarified my question.

Comment: i think you have set the selector on the Button Background. Otherwise it will not happen with it like you have said. I have tested it. And it works great in My case. Please check it. Please dont put any selector as background of Button or the ListItem. And try it.

Comment: But I want that the background of the button will be larger than the button size, and I can achieve it in that way, or you have other way? Take a look at my next [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027591/how-to-get-a-android-listview-item-selector-to-use-state-pressed)

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to connect the list a simpleAdapter. To accomplish what you are saying to will need a new class that extends BaseAdapter and change the background image on the getView event on that class.

Then on you main activity you can set an onlistItemClick to handle the click events for the list items.